# How do I chunk a list in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I want to rearrange a list into n-sized 'chunks':

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

where n=3 in this case.

What's an efficient way to do this in KDB that works for long lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sliding window

To achieve the output set out by your example you could use a modified version of this [sliding window](https://code.kx.com/q/kb/programming-idioms/#how-do-i-apply-a-function-to-a-sequence-sliding-window) function:

```
q){(x-1)_{ 1_x,y }\[x#0;y]}[3;til 10]
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
...
```

### Chunking a list

To cut a list into n sized chunks use the [take `#`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/take/#atom-or-list) operator. For example, when n=3:

```
q)0N 3#til 10
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
,9
```

The same notation can also be used to cut a list into n parts. For example n=3:

```
q)3 0N#til 10
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8 9
```

As stated in the docs:

> A null in x will cause that dimension to be maximal.

Comment: So I figured that part out; but the matrix I'm looking for (and in the example above) is different. Effectively I want to combine cut and take, so each row is shifted by 1 position.

Comment: How about a modified version of sliding window?
`{(x-1)_{ 1_x,y }\[x#0;y]}[3;til 10]`

Answer (score 2):

Could build a list of indices and index into your list. Not really sure what you want to do when there are less than 3/n for the cut. m below stops before nulls are populated. m2 below includes the nulls.

```
l:til 10;
m:{[n;l] @[l;(til n)+/: til neg[n-1]+count l]}

q)m[3;l]
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 7
6 7 8
7 8 9

q)m[4;l]
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
6 7 8 9

m2:{[n;l] @[l;(til n)+/: til count l]}
q)m2[4;l]
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
6 7 8 9
7 8 9
8 9
9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q)\ts:100 {flip til[x]+\:til 1+y-x}[3;1000000]
2181 97555184

q)\ts:100 {(x-1)_{ 1_x,y }\[x#0;y]}[3;til 1000000]
17120 89166928

q){flip til[x]+\:til 1+y-x}[3;1000000]~{(x-1)_{ 1_x,y }\[x#0;y]}[3;til 1000000]
1b
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another faster (though less memory efficient) solution that is generalisable to lists of all types (I believe user21344792's only works for numbers):

```
\ts:100 {x[] each -2_(til count x)+(count x)#enlist til y}[til 1000000;3]
8513 153166544
```

Here, working for a list of syms:

```
q){x[] each -2_(til count x)+(count x)#enlist til y}[`a`b`c`d`e`f`g`h`i`j`k;3]
a b c
b c d
c d e
d e f
e f g
f g h
g h i
h i j
i j k
```

The solution works by first generating a matrix of numbers, where the value of each row element is one bigger than the row "above" i.e.

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

This then serves as the list of values we want to index our list by to producde the cut

Answer (score 0):

Each column of the result is a `1_` of the preceding column. Use the [Scan form of Do](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#do)

```
q)flip{(til[x]-x-1)_'(x-1)_[1;]\y}[3] til 10
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 7
6 7 8
7 8 9
```

or Drop Each Left and Drop Each

```
q)flip{neg[reverse tx]_'(tx:til x)_\:y}[3] til 10
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 7
6 7 8
7 8 9
```